# How work counting True values in list of ints in Python?

Tags: python, list, count, boolean

Could someone explain me why in `for in l5` loop I got 2 True values, but from `l5.count(True)` I got only 1?? And why `l5.count(not 0)` returns only 1?

I know about other ways to get what I need: filter + lambda or sum + for + if, but I try understand it :)

Under part from Python console I've asked.

*Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32*
'''

```
l5 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
l5.count(True)
Out[3]: 1
for x in l5:
    print(x, bool(x))
    
0 False
0 False
0 False
1 True
2 True
l5.count(0)
Out[5]: 3
l5.count(not 0)
Out[6]: 1
l5.count(not False)
Out[7]: 1
```

'''

Comment: `count(True)` will list only 1 value because there is only "1"(True) in the list. But `bool(x)` will return 1 for every non-zero value of x. That is why you have 2 true(s).

Comment: Just because you can call ``bool`` on the items in the list and the result is ``True`` or ``False`` doesn't mean the list actually *contains* these booleans.

Comment: It was not clear for me, but now I understand what happened with that '2' in my list. Thanks guys for Ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`False` in python is numerically equal to `0` and `True` is numerically equal to `1`.

and so `not False` will be equal to `True` which will be numerically equal to `1`

```
l5 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
l5.count(True) # is equivalent to l5.count(1)
Out[3]: 1
l5.count(not 0) # is equivalent to l5.count(1)
Out[6]: 1
l5.count(not False) # is equivalent to l5.count(1)
Out[7]: 1
```

Also

```
l5.count(False) # is equivalent to l5.count(0)
Out[8]: 3
```

When you do `l5.count(True)`

Internally python check it with each element in the list `l5`

```
0==True ?
0==True ?
0==True ?
1==True ?
2==True ?
```

Now as `True` is `bool` type and others are `int`, python does an implicit type conversion from `bool` to `int` (as to do a comparison type should be same)

So as `True` is numerically equivalent to `1`:

```
Count=0

0==1 ? No
0==1 ? No
0==1 ? No
1==1 ? Yes; Count += 1 
2==1 ? No

Final output : 1
```

Now this was when type conversion from `bool` to `int`

In conversions from `int` to `bool`:

`0` is treated as `False` and everything other than `0` , -1,-2,-3,... 1,2,3,..  are treated as `True`.

and so

```
>>> bool(-1)
True

>>> bool(1)
True

>>> bool(2)
True

>>> bool(0)
False

>>> not 2
False

# as 2 is equivalent to True and "not True" is False
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)